# VB.net register keys while tabbed out

Tags: vb.net, tabs, keypress, tabbed

So I have this code that registers my key press CTRL + Numpad1

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad1 AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
        Label1.Text = "Hello"
    End If
```

But this only registers if this window is focus, for example the program won't register Ctrl + NumPad1 if I am playing like a game.

Thanks

Comment: You have to either register your hotkey combo with the RegisterHotKey() API, or use a low level keyboard hook trap your desired combination.

Comment: Idle_Mind could you perhaps be abit more detailed? Hans Passant, there is differnet between registering 2 hotkeys and 3 hotkeys. Useless post.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?672702-Register-Global-HotKeys) demonstrates the process, which dips into the Win32 API.

Comment: You cannot post just a link as an answer.  You'll need to describe the technique that's used there.  Important to keep answers still relevant when web pages disappear.  Lots of duplicates at SO as well btw, better to link to them.

Comment: I don't see how the link is relevant to my problem. "Note: Hotkeys can be overwritten if you will by other applications. If you register Ctrl+A, then afterwards a game does too. The game now has that hotkey and yours will no longer fire." Which won't work.